# How to do load testing using jmeter and visualVM?

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, visualvm, jvisualvm

I want to do load testing for 10 million users for my site. The site is a Java based web-app. My approach is to create a Jmeter test plan for all the links and then take a report for the 10 million users. Then use jvisualVM to do profiling and check if there are any bottlenecks.

Is there any better way to do this? Is there any existing demo for doing this? I am doing this for the first time, so any assistance will be very helpful.

Comment: My goal is to support for at least 10 million users.

Comment: Wow. That's a big question. A couple of up front questions: 10 Mill is a lot. Is that concurrent, unique users ? Are you fronting with native web servers ? Are you clustering the java app servers ? Will you use a load balancer ? Can you say which app server you will be using ? Will there be other dependencies like databases etc. ?

Comment: 10 million users in DB. I can do that with a PL/SQL procedure. 150 concurrent users. No clustering. Just staging machine. No load balancer. App server is Jetty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I blogged, the way I proceeded with the performance test:

1. Make sure that the server (hardware can be as per the staging/production requirements) has no other installations that can affect the performance.
2. For setting up the users in DB, a procedure can be used and can be called as a part of jmeter test plan.
3. Install jmeter on a separate machine, so that jmeter won't affect the performance.
4. Create a test plan in jmeter (as shown in the figure 1) for all the uri's, with response checking and timer based requests.
5. Take the initial benchmark, using jmeter.
6. Check for the low performance uri's. These are the points to expect for bottlenecks.
7. Try different options for performance improvement, but focus on only one bottleneck at a time.
8. Try any one fix from step 6 and then take an benchmark. If there is any improvement commit the changes and repeat from step 5. Otherwise revert and try for any other options from step 6.
9. The next step would be to use load balancing, hardware scaling, clustering, etc. This may include some physical setup and hardware/software cost. Give the results with the scalability options.

For detailed explanation: http://www.daemonthread.com/2011/06/site-performance-tuning-using-jmeter.html

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 7):

You are on the correct path, but your load limit is of with a high factor.

Why I'm saying this is cause your site probably will need more machine to handle 10Milj Concurrent users. A process alone would probably struggle to handle concurrent 32K TCP-streams. Also do some math of the bandwidth it would take to actually handle 10Milj users.

Now I do not know what kind of service you thinking of providing on your site, but when thinking of that JVisualVM slows down processing by a factor 10 (or more for method tracing), you would not actually measure the "real world" if you got JMeter and JVisualVM to work at the same time.

JVisualVM is more useful when you run on lower loads.

To create a good measurement first make sure your have a good baseline.
Make a test with 10 concurrent users, connect up JVisuamVM and let it run for a while, not down all interesting values.

After you have your baseline, then you can start adding more load.
Add 10times the load (ea: 100 users), look at the changes in JVisualVM. Continue this until it becomes obvious that JVisualVM slows you down, for every time to add extra load, make sure you have written down the numbers your are interested in. Plot down the numbers in a graph.

Now... Interpolate the graph (by hand) for the number of users you want. This works for memory usage, disc access etc, but not for used CPU time, cause JVisualVM will eat CPU and give you invalid numbers on that (especially if you have method tracing turned on).

If you really want to go as high as 10Milj users, I would not trust JMeter either, I would write a little test program of my own that performs the test you want. This would be okey, since the the setting up the site to handle 10Milj will also take time, so spending a little extra time of the test tools are not a waste.

Comment: Unix makes a very good point - make sure you have a good solid baseline and do a batch of tests with different concurrent users (10, 50, 100, 150) running each test for the same duration, and at least an hour in duration.

Comment: In last JDK release JVisualVM have sampling profiler which does not affect performance in order of magnitude. This type of profiling could be done on production servers even on moderate load.

Answer (score 3):

Just because you have 10 million users in the database, doesn't mean that you need to load test using that many users. Think about it - is your site really going to have 10 million *simultaneous* users? For web applications, a ratio of 1:100 registered users is common i.e. you are unlikely to have more than 100K users at any moment.

Can JMeter handle that kind of load? I doubt it. Please try [faban](http://faban.org) instead. It is very light-weight and can support thousands of users on a single VM. You also have much better flexibility in creating your workload and can also automate monitoring of your entire test infrastructure.

Now to the analysis part. You didn't say what server you were using. Any Java appserver will provide sufficient monitoring support. Commercial servers provide nice GUI tools while Tomcat provides extensive monitoring via JMX. You may want to start here before getting down to the JVM level.

For the JVM, you really don't want to use VisualVM while running such a large performance test. Besides to support such a load, I assume you are using multiple appserver/JVM instances. The major performance issue is usually GC, so use the JVM options to collect and log GC information. You will have to post-process the data.

This is a non-trivial exercise - good luck!

Comment: Please check the comments. I specified that 10 million users in DB and 150 concurrent users.

Comment: Sorry - missed that. Then it's important that you create your workload correctly to access either all or a sub-set of users based on what you are aiming at.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of load testing - bottleneck identification and throughput. The question leads me to believe this is about bottlenecks, so number of users is a something of a red herring, instead the goal being for a given configuration finding areas that can be improved to increase concurrency.

Application bottlenecks usually fall into three categories: database, memory leak, or slow algorithm. Finding them involves putting the application in question under stress (i.e. load) for an extended period of time - at least an hour, perhaps up to several days. Jmeter is a good tool for this purpose. One of the things to consider is running the same test with cookie handling enabled (i.e. Jmeter retains cookies and sends with each subsequent request) and disabled - sometimes you get very different results and this is important because the latter is effectively a simulation of what some crawlers do to your site. Details for bottleneck detection follow:

**Database**

Tables without indices or SQL statements involving multiple joins are frequent app bottlenecks. Every database server I've dealt with, MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle has some way of logging or identifying slow running SQL statements. MySQL has the slow query log, whereas SQL Server has dynamic management views that track the slowest running SQL. Once you've got your hands on the slow statements use explain plan to see what the database engine is trying to do, use any features that suggest indices, and consider other strategies - such as denormalization - if those two options do not solve the bottleneck.

**Memory Leak**

Turn on verbose garbage collection logging and a JMX monitoring port. Then use jConsole, which provides much better graphs, to observe trends. In particular leaks usually show up as filling the Old Gen or Perm Gen spaces. Leaks are a bottleneck with the JVM spends increasing amounts of time attempting garbage collection unsuccessfully until an OOM Error is thrown.

Perm Gen implies the need to increase the space as a command line parameter to the JVM. While Old Gen implies a leak where you should stop the load test, generate a heap dump, and then use Eclipse Memory Analysis Tool to identify the leak.

**Slow Algorithm**

This is more difficult to track down. The most frequent offenders are synchronization, inter process communication (e.g. RMI, web services), and disk I/O. Another common issue is code using nested loops (look mom O(n^2) performance!).

Best way I've found to find these issues absent some deeper knowledge is generating stack traces. These will tell what all threads are doing at a given point in time. What you're looking for are BLOCKED threads or several threads all accessing the same code. This usually points at some slowness within the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

I started using [JMeter plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/).
This allows me to gather application metrics available over JMX to use in my Load Test.